# How to restrict spider to crawl certain xPaths using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website, from product page i am trying to scrap product description but  how do i select only product description :

[link to page](http://www.basicslife.com/basics-casual-striped-green-100-cotton-muscle-t-shirt-33365.html)

```
xPath : hxs.select('//div[@class="product-shop"]/p/text()').extract()
```

The HTML is quite large so please see the link specified above..

I want only want to select product description not other details...

If i do this :

```
[" ".join([i.strip() for i in hxs.select('//div[@class="product-shop"]/p/text()').extract()])]

output : 
[u'Itemcode: 12BTS28271 Brand: BASICS InStock - Ships within 2 business days. Tip: 90% of our shipments reach within 4 business days! This product is part of the Basics T.shirts line made of 100% Cotton. Stripes Muscle Fit T.shirts that come in Green Color. Casual that comes with Henley away.']
```

But i want only :

```
[u'This product is part of the Basics T.shirts line made of 100% Cotton. Stripes Muscle Fit T.shirts that come in Green Color. Casual that comes with Henley away.']
```

Comment: Is there any regex or something to avoid unnecessary xPaths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rightclicking on the element in the elements panel in chrome tells me:

[image]

```
//*[@id="product_addtocart_form"]/div[2]/div[1]/p[3]
```

Points to

```
<p>This product is part of the Basics T.shirts line made of 100% Cotton.<br>
                        Stripes Muscle Fit T.shirts that come in Green Color.<br>
                        Casual that comes with Henley away.</p>
```

Trying the same XPATH on [this page](http://www.basicslife.com/basics-casual-plain-orange-100-cotton-slim-shirt-28965.html) also points to the description there too:

```
<p>This product is part of the Basics Shirts line made of 100% Cotton.<br>
                    Plain Slim Fit Shirts that come in Orange Color.<br>
                    Casual that comes with Button Down away.</p>
```

So it looks like all you need to do is call that XPATH on the page and you're set. You should still verify that that XPATH works in all cases though, as it's always prone to change depending on the page.

Comment: Thanks man i did not knew that xPath can also be written like `div[2]`..that....thanks